# Python 3.6 CSV Date Formatting d/m/yyyy to ddmmyyyy

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a date column in a CSV file which I am trying to format from dd/mm/yyyy to ddmmyyyy. Some of the days and months are single digit which leave them as dmyyyy. When I run a print statement all of the rows output correctly.

```
import csv 

with open(r'input file path,'r') as csvfile:
   with open(r'outputfilepath,'w') as output:
    w = csv.writer(output)
    r = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for row in r:
        #this takes care of incomplete rows at the end
        if len(row[6])>1:
            dt = row[6].split("/")
            n = 0
            for n in range(len(dt)):
                if len(dt[n])<2:
                   dt[n] = '0'+dt[n]
                else:
                   dt[n]
            row[6] = dt[0]+dt[1]+dt[2]
            print(row)

        else:
            break
```

Print Output:

```
['a', '', 'Tom', 'Smith', 'J ', '', '12201956']
['b', '', 'Rick ', 'JOHNSON ', ' ', '', '08121922']
['c', '', 'Morty', 'Harvey', ' ', '', '06031940']
```

When I change the print to write rows:

```
import csv 

with open(r'input file path,'r') as csvfile:
   with open(r'outputfilepath,'w') as output:
    w = csv.writer(output)
    r = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for row in r:
        #this takes care of incomplete rows at the end
        if len(row[6])>1:
            dt = row[6].split("/")
            n = 0
            for n in range(len(dt)):
                if len(dt[n])<2:
                   dt[n] = '0'+dt[n]
                else:
                   dt[n]
            row[6] = dt[0]+dt[1]+dt[2]
            w.writerows(row)

        else:
            break
```

I get the output below. I've tried moving the `writerows` function around with no luck. Looking at the CSV module documentation it should delimit on the commas. I'm relatively new to python.
[image]

Comment: Change `w.writerows(row)` to `w.writerow(row)`.  Plural vs singular.  You would also be well-served to be adding `newline=''` to your `open()` because the `csv` writer does its own newline handling.  That would explain the extra newlines in your already messed up data.

Comment: `row[6] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[6],'%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%m%d%Y')`

Comment: Why not `row[6].replace('/', '')`? Don't need to `import datetime`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski You should put that as an answer.

Comment: @Idlehands: He's doing dates that are sometimes missing leading zeros.  Like `1/11/2018` or `12/1/2017`.  That can be handled with string methods, but it can be handled entirely mindlessly with datetime methods.  It takes a bit more thought to write `''.join(x.zfill(2) for x in row[6].split('/'))`.  More importantly though is it's clear to the reader what the datetime method is doing.

Comment: I misunderstood - I thought he meant the input was always dd/mm/yyyy and he wants to convert to ddmmyyyy with variations of dmmyyyy ddmyyyy dmyyyy expected (which is disastrous IMO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your problem change `w.writerows(row)` to `w.writerow(row)`.  The difference is between the singular and the plural is that the plural version thinks its getting a collection of rows to write.  It treats each item in the row you gave as a single row.

Also `newline=''` to your `open` because the `csv` module interacts poorly with universal newline mode on windows.  (It tries to write `'\r\n'`.  Universal newline translates that to `'\r\r\n'`.)

Finally, use `datetime` to fix your dates.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open(inpath, 'r', newline='') as fin: 
    with open(outpath, 'w', newline='') as fout:
        reader = csv.reader(fin)
        writer = csv.writer(fout)
        for row in reader:
            row[6] = datetime.strptime(row[6], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%m%d‌​%Y')
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir for the exceptionally great and thorough explanation.   Changing "writerows" to "writerow" worked perfectly. When I attempted to run the code you provided I received an "invalid syntax" error on the second open statement. This was fixed by adding a "with" before the second open. It now throws an encoding error. I will try to track down the culprit and fix the characters. Thank you again.